# React relay pendingVariables always null after setVariables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, relayjs

When i try to set a variable, the component updates only after fetch is complete. Here is an exapmle code.

```
class RelayExample extends React.Component {
  setVars() {
    this.props.relay.setVariables({id: '2'});
  };
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.relay.pendingVariables);
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.setVars.bind(this)}>set variable</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

RelayExample = Relay.createContainer(RelayExample, {
  initialVariables: {
    id: '1'
  },
  fragments: {
    userStore: ()=> {
      return Relay.QL`
      fragment on userStore {
         user(id:$id){
          email
         }
      }
      `;
    }
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Relay.RootContainer Component={RelayExample} route={new TestQuery()}/>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

When i press the button i get this result in console:
[image]

Even if i use forceUpdate right after the setVariables function, i get similar result.

```
setVars() {
        this.props.relay.setVariables({id: '2'});
        this.forceUpdate();
};
```

[image]

Comment: The environment is Relay.Store

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is intended behaviour.

> pendingVariables contains the set of variables that are being used to
>   fetch the new props, i.e. when this.props.relay.setVariables() or
>   this.props.relay.forceFetch() are called and the corresponding request
>   is in flight.
>
> If no request is in flight pendingVariables is null.

If you console log right after you set your variables you should see them in `pendingVariables`.

Comment: if i am not wrong, according to  [this](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/api-reference-relay-container.html#pendingvariables) example the component must update after setVariables and the pendingVariables must be fulfilled.

Comment: This is not the intented behavior. Having same problem here.